# EPIServer CMS Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, episerver, episerver-6

I'm trying to use EPIServer Webservice ContentChannelService.asmx to import files to a specific property on a page.

I create the pages programatically and after this I want to use the webservice to populate a "linktoimage" property. Now I have succeded in just uploading a file to the root of the filesystem but as you understand I want to connect it to the page's property.

How do I do this? (I have the page's id so I can fetch the page) Tips, tricks or solutions is very welcome!

Thanks!

EDIT
I'm open to use the PageMirroringService.asmx and PageStoreService.asmx as well just don't know exactly how to use them to make it work as I want.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a content channel.

[This](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Jeff-Wallace/Dates/2010/3/Pushing-Data-into-EPiServer-CMS-5-via-Content-Channels/) article might be of assistance to you

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the methode ImoprtFile2() and then use the string that was returned to set the property value of the iamge property. It's not that well documented so it feels like you have to try and error until you get what you want.